# Remove specific line in a string

Tags: php, string

I want to convert a string in the following way.

Input string:

```
WB - KU - 5VWB1\nWB - KU - 5VWB1 (WB - KU - 5VWB1)\nlokaal 2.06
```

Expected output string:

```
WB - KU - 5VWB1\nlokaal 2.06
```

Where: `"WB - KU - 5VWB1 (WB - KU - 5VWB1)"` Could be anything. There are always 3 lines. And I always want to remove the second line.

EDIT:

My current state/code:

```
$data = explode("\n", $event["DESCRIPTION"]);
```

Gives:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(63) "WB - KU - 5VWB1\nWB - KU - 5VWB1 (WB - KU - 5VWB1)\nlokaal 2.06" }
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: explode on line break --- seems trivial

Comment: explode on `"\n"`, unset the element you don't want, implode using  `"\n"` as glue

Comment: $data = explode("\n", $event["DESCRIPTION"]) gives: array(1) { [0]=> string(63) "WB - KU - 5VWB1\nWB - KU - 5VWB1 (WB - KU - 5VWB1)\nlokaal 2.06" }

Comment: @JasperPeters So you don't really have new lines, when I see this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version 1 string `\n`

```
$x='WB - KU - 5VWB1\nWB - KU - 5VWB1 (WB - KU - 5VWB1)\nlokaal 2.06';

$y=explode("\\n",$x); //string /n

print_r($y);
```

version 2 actual line breaks:

```
$x="WB - KU - 5VWB1\nWB - KU - 5VWB1 (WB - KU - 5VWB1)\nlokaal 2.06";

$y=explode("\n",$x); //actual line break

print_r($y);
```

result of both:

Array ( [0] => WB - KU - 5VWB1 [1] => WB - KU - 5VWB1 (WB - KU - 5VWB1) [2] => lokaal 2.06 )

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Just concatenate the substring from the start until the first new line and the substring from the last new line, e.g.

So what you do:

```
             Start of the string                           End of the string
             |          Position of                        Position of     |
             |       the first new line                 the last new line  |
             ↓              ↓↓                                 ↓↓          ↓
string:     "WB - KU - 5VWB1\nWB - KU - 5VWB1 (WB - KU - 5VWB1)\nlokaal 2.06"
             └───────┬──────┘                                  └─────┬─────┘
                     |                                               |
substring(s): "WB - KU - 5VWB1"              .                 "\nlokaal2.06"
                     └───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┘
                                             |
result:                         "WB - KU - 5VWB1\nlokaal"
```

Code:

```
$str = "WB - KU - 5VWB1\nWB - KU - 5VWB1 (WB - KU - 5VWB1)\nlokaal 2.06";
echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str, PHP_EOL)) . substr($str, strrpos($str, PHP_EOL));
```

output:

```
WB - KU - 5VWB1
lokaal 2.06
```

**EDIT:**

As it seems in the comments, you have literally `\n` in your string, so repace `strpos($str, PHP_EOL)` and `strrpos($str, PHP_EOL)` just with `strpos($str, '\n')`, `strrpos($str, '\n')`.